# Have NUNIT run tests in parallel

Tags: c#, nunit

I have a DBContext within my tests for EF Core

Each test is responsible for setting up this context

How can I get NUnit to be able to run my tests in parallel with each test having its own dbContext where the dbcontext is a field of the class

It appears as though each run is reusing the fields in the test class, I want a brand new instance created for each test?

Following the answer below I added FixtureLifeCycleAttribute.InstancePerTest to the top of my test class

```
    protected virtual DbContext GetDbContext()
    {

        if (_dbContext == null)
        {
            var testName = TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.MethodName + "_" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            Debug.WriteLine($"Creating context for {testName}");
            

            // Create a fresh service provider, and therefore a fresh 
            // InMemory database instance.
            var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
                .AddEntityFrameworkInMemoryDatabase()
                .BuildServiceProvider();

            // Create a new options instance telling the context to use an
            // InMemory database and the new service provider.
            var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyDbContext>();
            builder.UseInMemoryDatabase(testName).UseInternalServiceProvider(serviceProvider);

            var options = builder.Options;
            var result = new MyDbContext(options);

            if (ShareContext == false)
            {
                return result;
            }

            _dbContext = result;
        }

        return _dbContext;
    }
```

I use this

protected MyDbContext DbContext => (MyDbContext)GetDbContext();

So in my tests I add to DbContext.MyTable

If I have 2 separate tests that add the same record to DbContext.MyTable I would not expect this to fail but it does

Paul

Comment: Please include some code showing what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

In version 3.13, Nunit has added a support for instance per test case by simply choosing LifeCycle.InstancePerTestCase value when placing the FixtureLifeCycleAttribute on top of the test class. See docs here https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/attributes/fixturelifecycle.html

Comment: Thanks!  This looks good, but Im not sure how to apply to the whole solution in one place, I have a base test, Im hoping I can add it there

Comment: I have done this and it doesnt work?  I am getting errors with my DbContext that would only happen if the context is being shared, not if new instances were being created?

Comment: If you want this attribute to be assigned on all test classes within the project, you need to put this attribute on the assembly level.
See here how to define an attribute on the assembly level:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/

Or to shorten this up for you: place the following declaration on top of the base test class namespace:
[assembly:  FixtureLifeCycle(LifeCycle.InstancePerTestCase)]